# Testing that a JS module is CommonJS or AMD compatible

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, gruntjs, amd, commonjs

Is there a way to test automatically if a JavaScript module is compatible with CommonJS (Node) or AMD module formats? Furthermore, how could one write it as a Grunt task?

Compability is an important feature of a module and should be able to be tested automatically at least in some degree. For example a change in a building configuration could produce a compability error that cannot be noticed by unit tests that use only browser interface of the module, like is the case with QUnit. There might be also possibility that the compability-enabling code of a module (e.g. self-made [UMD wrapper](https://github.com/umdjs/umd)) is so messy that it is hard to say if a change elsewhere in the code could have an effect on the compability part of the code.

One could use tools that generate probably correct wrappers of different module formats. For example [grunt-umd](https://github.com/bebraw/grunt-umd) and [uRequire](http://urequire.org/) are such tools. But as they too depend on the build configuration, how you can be sure that the compability really is there without any testing?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an out-of-the-box or obvious solution.

In general there are several approaches you could take to solve your problem:

1. Write your code in one module format and use transpilers to produce the other module formats. Babel (5) is pretty good at doing this, but there are probably others.
2. Use a parser like [esprima](http://esprima.org/) and statically analyze the code. The "standard" wrappers like those on https://github.com/umdjs/umd are probably easy to detect patterns. Custom wrappers might be harder and you might need a few revisions before you get it all right.
3. Trial-and-error: Have your grunt task create files (e.g. generated from .jade templates) that include the supposed module in each of the manners you care about (AMD, browser globals), then "run" those (e.g. using nightwatch or selenium) and see if any errors occur. (This might be very difficult to get right if the module you are trying to load has dependencies)